# Hibernate envers: combined annotations @Audited and @AttributeOverride not working

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to come up with an audited entity by means of Hibernate envers feature.
I have a base class: Result

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "result")
public class Result {

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = @Column(name = "id"))
    private ResultId id;

    @Audited
    @Column
    private String value;

    @Audited
    @AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = @Column(name = "updated_by"))
    private PersonId updatedBy;

}
```

In application I make changes for the entity **value** and **updated_by** fields. But in audit table I see only changes for **value** property, but **updated_by** always has NULL. It seems to me that `@Audited` and `@AttributeOverride` is not compatible.

How can I achieve auditing for **updated_by** field?

Comment: Why the `@AttributeOverride` in the first place?

Comment: I have a Generic Id entity with protected string value field. And my PersonId extends that Generic id entity. In database I want to store that value in `updated_by` column. So I find that I can map it via that annotation @AttributeOverride. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`@AuditOverride`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/AuditOverride.html) rather than the `@Audited`, as you are overriding the default audit behaviour of the field.